# Issue installing Kubernetes on AWS EC2 / ubuntu 16.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I want to test kubernetes for gitlab-ci, so I want to create my first k8s cluster on aws

So I follow the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/):

```
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
# re-login may be required at that point if you just installed snap utility
conjure-up kubernetes
```

In the install process, I choose:

- Canonical Distribution of Kubernetes
- Helm
- AWS
- my credentials
- us-east-2
- Juju-as-a-Service (JaaS) Free Controller

Then I must log into JaaS. I log entering my Ubuntu One account, but it always fail:

```
 Login failed, please try again: ERROR cannot log into "jimm.jujucharms.com": cannot get user details for "https://login.ubuntu.com/+id/W8KzXrQ":
                  not found
```

What am I forgetting ?

Comment: This sounds like an ubuntu or jujucharms question, and nothing specific to kubernetes. My recommendation for installing clusters is always to use [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray#readme) because of its transparency (including running it in Vagrant, to see what it is going to do)